# Как создать триггер в SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql

При этом должен создаваться архив, в который будет скидываться таблица до изменений.
Например: в таблицу добавляется строка, прежде, чем ее добавить, необходимо содержимое таблицы скинуть в архив (в виде log файла). Все это для сохранности данных (чтобы не произошла потеря информации).

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как в архив, но можно сделать дублирующую таблицу в которую перед изменением будет сохранятся информация которую меняют, но перед изменением. примерно так

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER users_autintif BEFORE UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MONITORING
SELECT *
FROM table
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать)